# How can i use substring in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I rearrange string with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634240/how-can-i-rearrange-string-with-sql)

```
Declare @CustTotalCount as int
Declare @CustMatchCount as int 
 select @CustTotalCount = count(*)  from ENG_CUSTOMERTALLY

 select @CustMatchCount = count(*)  from Task  where MPDReference in(
 select ENG_CUSTOMERTALLY_CUSTOMERTASKNUMBER from dbo.ENG_CUSTOMERTALLY)

if(@CustTotalCount>@CustMatchCount)
select distinct
 substring(ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO, charindex('-', ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
 + 1, 1000)
  from dbo.ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS where
 ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_CUSTOMER_NUMBER in(
select ENG_CUSTOMERTALLY_CUSTOMERTASKNUMBER from ENG_CUSTOMERTALLY1
except
select MPDReference from Task )
```

i can convert below string data

- A320-200001-01-1(1)
- A320-200001-01-1(2)
- A320-200001-01-1(1)

TO

- 200001-01-1(1)
- 200001-01-1(2)
- 200001-01-1(1)

But i need

- 200001-01-1
- 200001-01-1
- 200001-01-1

distict ---> 200001-01-1
How can i do that SQL and C# ?

Comment: try keeping it all in one post, i've counted 3 with basically the same problem so far

Comment: This is nearly an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634240/how-can-i-rearrange-string-with-sql/3634270#3634270, but just asks a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave this answer in the duplicate question too.

Here's a technique that uses `PATINDEX`, which can use wild cards.

```
SUBSTRING(ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO,
        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO),
        PATINDEX('%(%', ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                 - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                )
```

The start for your substring is the position of the first numeric value (%[0-9]%).  The length value is the position of the first parenthesis ('%(%') less the starting position.

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(....) FROM ...
```